# Beamer: have text start from a fixed location on each slide

Tags: beamer

I have a custom pdf background to my slides and I don't want text to obscure a certain part of the background. Is there anyway I can force beamer to have text start from a certain place on the slides, rather than trying to fill the whole thing with text?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.0cm}` to specify the left margin.

From the Section 8.3 of the documentation the options that can be specified with `\setbeamersize` are:

> - `text margin left=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets a new left margin. This excludes the left sidebar. Thus, it
>     is the distance between the right edge of the left sidebar and the left edge of the text.
> - `text margin right=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets a new right margin.
> - `sidebar width left=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets the size of the left sidebar. Currently, this command
>     should be given before a shading is installed for the sidebar canvas.
> - `sidebar width right=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets the size of the right sidebar.
> - `description width=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets the default width of description labels
> - `description width of=⟨text⟩` sets the default width of description labels to the width of the ⟨text⟩
> - `mini frame size=⟨TEX dimension⟩` sets the size of mini frames in a navigation bar. When two mini
>     frame icons are shown alongside each other, their left end points are `⟨TEX dimension⟩` far apart.
> - `mini frame offset=⟨TEX dimension⟩` set an additional vertical offset that is added to the mini frame size when arranging mini frames vertically.